Guidewire Financials Voiding a check results in a "No transactions to save" Java.Financials.Exception.EmptyTransactionSet
We are running into a problem with Voiding checks. This scenario is a claim handler manually pressing the Void check button. Then we run this logic
 function voidCheck() {
      try {
        gw.api.util.CCLocationUtil.runAndCommit(\-> {
          if (Check.isInternalCostPayment or Check.isFrontingPayment) {
            Logger.info("Voiding Internal Cost Check" + Check.PublicID)
            Check.voidCheck()
            Check.updateCheckStatus(Check.CheckNumber, Date.CurrentDate.toCalendar(), TransactionStatus.TC_VOIDED)
            Logger.info("Voided Internal Cost Check" + Check.PublicID)
          } else {
            Logger.info("Voiding Check and Triggering Disbursement" + Check.PublicID)
            DisbursementVoidDetails.Instance.invokeVoidService(Check)
            Logger.info("Triggerred Disbursement service and got response" + Check.PublicID)
            Check.voidCheck()
            Logger.info("Check set to Pending void (${Check.Status})")
          }
        }, CurrentLocation)
      } catch (e : IllegalStateException) {
        throw new gw.api.util.DisplayableException(DisplayKey.get("Web.Financials.CheckCancel.Error.IllegalFinancialsStatus"), e)
      } catch (all : Exception){
        Logger.error("Exception encountered during voiding of check: ${Check.PublicID} for claim ${Check.Claim.ClaimNumber} with message ",#voidCheck(),all)
        throw new gw.api.util.DisplayableException(DisplayKey.get("Web.Financials.CheckCancel.Error.void"))
      }
    }

In logs I can see the message that the Check was created, acknowledged by integration and then 30 sec after the user manually voided the check but got the exception. I was unable to reproduce the same error in lower env. where I could put break points.
My suspect is the runAndCommit() function since I was unable to reproduce the scenario in local I cannot confirm the exact fault.
Any recommendations?

In the environment that is throwing the error, which part of the if/else statement is the logic going through? Does the check go into the if (Check.isInternalCostPayment or Check.isFrontingPayment) part or the else part?

I can't say for sure what your root cause is but here is one thing that is coded incorrectly.
This snippet of violates a rule around only updating the check status in Messaging Plugins. You can call voidCheck() which will update the check status to Pending Void. But the calling of updateCheckStatus from a PCF is not allowed. You should be calling updateCheckStatus from Messaging Plugin (either a request plugin or reply plugin) after you have received an affirmative acknowledgement from the check printing or downstream system that the check has been voided.
if (Check.isInternalCostPayment or Check.isFrontingPayment) {
  Logger.info("Voiding Internal Cost Check" + Check.PublicID)
  Check.voidCheck()
  Check.updateCheckStatus(Check.CheckNumber, Date.CurrentDate.toCalendar(), TransactionStatus.TC_VOIDED)
  Logger.info("Voided Internal Cost Check" + Check.PublicID)
}

Take a look at this warning that I copied from the GW documentation linked here (login required)
https://docs.guidewire.com/self-managed/cc/1023/integration/integration/cc/topics/c_oq3079348.html

You can use these methods only in the following specific contexts. Using the methods in other contexts is unsupported and has unpredictable results.

Only from messaging plugins. Never use these methods from rule sets or other Gosu or Java contexts.
Only after submitting the acknowledgment for a message. If this message is associated with status transitions that occur only by calling the financials acknowledgment APIs, call those APIs first before attempting other status changes. Make the calls either in your MessageTransport plugin after a synchronous send and acknowledgment or in your MessageReply plugin after your asynchronous acknowledgment of the message.



As I mentioned its hard to fully debug this case but I will remove the updateCheckStatus as you are correct that this function shouldn't be called from PCF.

In the logs you should be able to see what path the check goes in the if/then statement. The public ID of the check is logged and you have a different log message depending on which path the check follows.
